# Why is my widget screen not displaying content?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have this page I'm trying to design in XD :
[image: Pay Bills (Arabic)]

and when I ran the application to render in , the bottom side with content containing the tab did not display and I get these errors but I don't know what they exactly mean :

> > I/flutter (22774): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderViewport#cc2f4 NEEDS-LAYOUT
> > NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE: I/flutter (22774):   needs
> > compositing I/flutter (22774):   creator: Viewport ←
> > IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#1f28b] ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ←
> > Listener ← I/flutter (22774):     _GestureSemantics ←
> > RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#0f747] ←
> > I/flutter (22774):     _PointerListener ← Listener ← _ScrollableScope
> > ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#03bee] ← I/flutter (22774):
> > RepaintBoundary ← ⋯ I/flutter (22774):   parentData:  (can use
> > size) I/flutter (22774):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=360.0,
> > 0.0<=h<=Infinity) I/flutter (22774):   size: MISSING I/flutter (22774):   axisDirection: left I/flutter (22774):
> > crossAxisDirection: down I/flutter (22774):   offset:
> > _PagePosition#dd846(offset: null, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, I/flutter (22774):     _ForceImplicitScrollPhysics ->
> > PageScrollPhysics -> PageScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics ->
> > I/flutter (22774):     ClampingScrollPhysics ->
> > RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#2467d, I/flutter
> > (22774):     ScrollDirection.idle) I/flutter (22774):   anchor: 0.0
> > I/flutter (22774): This RenderObject had the following descendants
> > (showing up to depth 5): I/flutter (22774):     center child:
> > _RenderSliverFractionalPadding#2da9f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE I/flutter (22774):       child:
> > RenderSliverFillViewport#a0715 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
> > NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE I/flutter (22774):
> > ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> > I/flutter (22774): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not
> > laid out: RenderViewport#cc2f4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
> > NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATEI/flutter (22774): Another exception was
> > thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#cc2f4 NEEDS-PAINT
> > NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE I/flutter (22774): Another exception was
> > thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#d6f43
> > relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> > I/flutter (22774): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not
> > laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#55aed relayoutBoundary=up9
> > NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE I/flutter (22774): Another
> > exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> > RenderPointerListener#891d5 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
> > NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE I/flutter (22774): Another exception was
> > thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> > RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#40649 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
> > NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE I/flutter (22774): Another exception was
> > thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#0e00a
> > relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> > I/flutter (22774): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not
> > laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#61006 relayoutBoundary=up5
> > NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE I/flutter (22774): Another
> > exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> > RenderRepaintBoundary#782fb relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
> > NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE I/flutter (22774): Another exception was
> > thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#3bc15
> > relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> > I/flutter (22774): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not
> > laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#e1816 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
> > NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE I/flutter (22774): Another exception was
> > thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#20580
> > relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> > I/flutter (22774): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError:
> > The method '>' was called on null.

my code is : paybills.dart file (main widget displaying both tabs)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../constans/constants.dart';
import 'first_tab.dart';
import 'second_tab.dart';

class PayBills extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PayBillsState createState() => _PayBillsState();
}

class _PayBillsState extends State<PayBills>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text(
          'تسديد فاتورة',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: leaderLogo,
            fontSize: 24,
            fontFamily: 'Calibri',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(children: [
          Container(
            height: 93,
            width: 378,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: TabBar(
                controller: _controller,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'فواتير مستحقة',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'فواتير مدفوعة',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TabBarView(
            controller: _controller,
            children: [
              PayBillsList(),
              SecondTab(),
            ],
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is firsttab.dart file displaying the first tab :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../constans/constants.dart';

class BillDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final String billName;
  final String billImage;
  final String billDate;

  const BillDetails({Key key, this.billName, this.billImage, this.billDate})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Container(
          width: 40,
          height: 40,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(billImage),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          )),
        ),
        title: Text(
          billName,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Calibri',
            fontSize: 16,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        subtitle: Text(
          billDate,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Calibri',
            fontSize: 12,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
        trailing: PayButton(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PayBillsList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<BillDetails> billsList = [
    BillDetails(
      billName: 'فاتورة كهرباء',
      billImage: 'assets/images/electricity.png',
      billDate: '30 / 4 / 2020',
    ),
    BillDetails(
      billName: 'فاتورة مياه',
      billImage: 'assets/images/water.png',
      billDate: '30 / 4 / 2020',
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 378,
      height: 93,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          width: 1,
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return BillDetails(
            billName: billsList.elementAt(index).billName,
            billImage: billsList.elementAt(index).billImage,
            billDate: billsList.elementAt(index).billDate,
          );
        },
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: billsList.length,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PayButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const PayButton({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: 80,
      height: 40,
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        color: raisedButtonColor,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
              //Login button text properties
              'دفع',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontFamily: 'Calibri',
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```